# Admin file upload assigned to specific users

Tags: views, 8

I'm looking for a way to allow the administrator to upload files. These files will be for specific site users (think receipts, test scores, etc) and can only be viewed by that specific user.

**Things i've tried:**

- Groups - creating a group for every user is a no go
- Nodeaccess - doesn't work properly in D8

Site is running latest version of Drupal 8.

Any modules or direction will be helpful.

Comment: I think there is a module called Access By Entity which sets role and (I think) user id level access to any entity.

Comment: @Kevin I looked at that module, still requires permissions per role. What i'm looking for is file permission per user, not role/category/group/type. It may not be something Drupal offers but I wanted to make sure before I go down the custom code route.

Comment: If there is no contrib module to do this the following module https://www.drupal.org/project/file_view_access  it might be a good starting point for a custom module.

Comment: I'm looking for same thing. Admin uploads reports for each user, not role.

Comment: Havn't tested it but I'm thinking adding a file (multiple) type field to user profile and allowing admin to upload files to it will work. User is an entity so the file field will have different value for each user instance.